# Can / Should I put project budgets on my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search

I work as an engineering manager. I am wondering if it is commonly-accepted practice to put your projects' financial budgets on your resume and discuss them in interviews. I'm thinking something like the following (I am making up a number):

- Managed a $1M engineering budget

So if you could answer these questions directly, I would appreciate it:

1. Can/should you put these budgets on your resume (paper/PDF)?
2. Can you put it on LinkedIn or other publicly-viewable site?
3. Can you discuss it at the interviews?

Obviously, I do not want to ask my current company whether or not it is ok with them.

Answer (score 7):

I personally see nothing wrong with answering yes to all 3 questions.  One purpose of resumes and interviews is to go over your accomplishments.  It is an accomplishment to manage a budget that large and it indicates a measure of trust your employer had with you.  As long as you don't violate any NDA's and start revealing details that you shouldn't (which only you can determine) I don't see any problem with that at all.  It's no different than listing any other achievement.

Just be vague on the details if you need to in order to avoid the perception of telling things that you shouldn't. But I've seen many people include this information in the same way they would any other achievements. So it seems like a rather common practice to me, at least in my experience.

Comment: Totally right on. I use a web safe resume that has no actual name/address of employers that is first contact. My actual resume used (next in escalation) has all the redacted info filled in. I don't list actual numbers, such as budget (there are parallels to software dev for product expense like user base, unique hits, etc). I use vague numbers or other linguistic tools to solicit questions on the budget (in your case) making the item a good point of interview conversation.  I am vague b/c I know what happens to resumes in an office, passed around/etc. So I keep info minimal always.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is there nothing wrong with this, it's a good idea.

I've seen many job postings that explicitly require experience managing a budget.

Not all managers have budget experience, and this will set you apart in a positive way.